# How can i distunguish two get routes with same parameters?

Tags: node.js, express

I have two routes.

```
app.get('/api/v1/bucket/:bucket_name', (req, res) => {

  queries.getAllFilesFromSpecificBucket(req.params.bucket_name).then(data => {
    res.json(data);
  });
})

app.get('/api/v1/bucket/:file_name', (req, res) => {
  queries.getSpecificFileByName(req.params.file_name).then(data => {
    res.json(data);
  });
})
```

The path by the two of them is same api/v1/bucket/ except the parameter name.Here my problem is that when i try go get the route with file_name parameter,always gets called the first route with the bucket_name parameter.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work if your bucketname doesn't have `.` in it and the file name always have an extension

```js
app.get('/api/v1/bucket/:name', (req, res) => {
    const name = req.params.name;
    if (name.includes(".")) {
        queries.getSpecificFileByName(name).then(data => {
            res.json(data);
        });
    } else {
        queries.getAllFilesFromSpecificBucket(name).then(data => {
            res.json(data);
        });
    }
})
```

What this code will do is checks if `:name` has `.` or not, if it does, then it will get file by filename, if it's not, then it will get all files inside the bucket name

For example:

- `example.jpg` -> file
- `.example` -> file
- `example` -> bucket

But if you want to make it more *REST*, then I think it makes more sense to change your route path, like:

- `/api/v1/buckets/:bucketName/files`: get all files inside a bucket
- `/api/v1/buckets/:bucketName/files/:fileName`: get a file by file name inside a bucket
- `/api/v1/files/:fileName`: get a file by filename on any bucket

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is to just change one of your api routes. Another option is to combine the the routes and use a query parameter

```
app.get('/api/v1/bucket/:name', (req, res) => {
  if (req.query.bucket === "true") {
   //DO bucket logic
  } else {
  // DO file logic
  }
})
```

For this to work you need to update your front-end route to something like this

```
const getBucket = `/api/v1/bucket/${bucketName}?bucket=true`
const getFile = `/api/v1/bucket/${fileName}?bucket=false` // NOTE you can just remove the ?bucket=false from this line
```